# Why does the general form of an Hamiltonian of a qubit for a two level system have all real entries?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hamiltonian

I understand that Hamiltonian has to be hermitian. For a two level system, why does the general form of an Hamiltonian of a qubit have all real entries :
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{array}{cc} \epsilon & \delta \\ \delta & -\epsilon \end{array} \right)
$$
where $\epsilon$ as the offset between the potential energy and $\delta$ as the matrix element for tunneling between them.

Or equivalently in the following form why is there an absence of $\sigma_y$ term:
$$H=\frac{1}{2} \delta\sigma_x + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon\sigma_z \,.$$

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: The assumption is wrong. The Hamiltonian for a two level system is not always purely real.

Comment: Although if the Hamiltonian is time independent, then you can pick a basis in which it is not only real, but proportional to $\sigma_z$.

Comment: Would this paper from Arxiv be helpful? https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1645

Comment: @Astrangequark That seems like overkill, as the paper is about two-qubit gates, while this question is about one-qubit gates.

Comment: @DanielSank for time-dependence, i think this also holds for hamiltonian used in quantum annealing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the time-independent case, you can think of the Hamiltonian as specified by a  constant 'magnetic field vector'
$$H \sim \mathbf{B} \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}.$$
By rotating your frame, you rotate the field, and hence change the coefficients of the $\sigma_i$. For example, you could rotate so that your $z$ axis is parallel to $\mathbf{B}$, so that the Hamiltonian becomes
$$H \sim \sigma_z.$$
This is equivalent to diagonalizing the Hamiltonian.

However, in most applications, there's a special axis picked out (e.g. by an external field) conventionally called the $z$ axis, which we don't want to change. That means we're only allowed to do rotations in the $xy$ plane. In general, such a rotation can always set $B_y = 0$, giving the form
$$H \sim a \sigma_z + b \sigma_x$$
which is exactly what you have.

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily set the field to have $B_y=0$.

Comment: @DanielSank Can you explain? If $H$ is constant and you're allowed $xy$ rotations, you can always rotate away an $x$ component or $y$ component. This is why we can draw these fields on a 2D sheet of paper.

Comment: @DanielSank Of course this doesn't hold for time dependence, but every term written in the OP is manifestly time independent.

Comment: Yeah *if* $H$ is time independent. Maybe add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A Hamiltonian is only defined up to a unitary transformation.

One can apply the unitary $U(\theta) = e^{i \sigma_z \theta /2}$ to the Hamiltonian you wrote to obtain:
$$
U\hat{H}U^\dagger = 
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon & \delta e^{i\theta} \\
\delta e^{-i\theta} & -\epsilon
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So $\theta$ can always be chosen to make the matrix elements real.

Comment: According to your logic, one could always choose $\delta=0$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch note that the unitary transformation defined by TheTD does not change the modulus of $\delta$, so no: it cannot be used to set $\delta=0$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform but why should one limit oneself to thos kind of unitary transform?

Comment: Typo: One of the $\delta$s needs to be the complex conjugate of the other.

Comment: @lalala nobody said you should. The TD just suggested *one* type of unitary transformations, which in this case does the trick, so it is good enough for our purposes. Of course you can consider other unitary transformations, but they are not very relevant to this particular question.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I think, Norbert / lalala raised a valid very question: If the Hamiltonian is only defined up to a unitary, we can not only transform the phase away, but we can make it diagonal. Why should the unitary transformations here be limited to those that only change the phase, and why are the others "not very relevant to this particular question"? And I want to add: Why is a Hamiltonian "only defined up to a unitary transformation"?

Comment: @Noiralef again, you misunderstood the point of this answer. The unitary transformations are **not** limited to those that only change the phase. The point of this answer is that: *if* there is a phase, we can always rotate it away. Nobody said that you can *only* do that. Perhaps you can do other things with other unitary transformations. OP asked why we can omit the phase, and The TD explained why. That's it, no more no less.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform lalala and Noiralef indeed got my point: The answer starts by stating *"A Hamiltonian is only defined up to a unitary transformation."*  This doesn't make much sense.  And if it would, we could indeed chose another transformation which would make $H$ diagonal. It really depends what we are interested in,  but in this generality the statement is not justified.  Neither is it clear why the specific unitary chosen later makes sense here.  Again, it depends on what is interested in.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Regarding your last comment above: Just because it gives the right result, it does not mean the argument is valid. From a wrong statement, anything can be inferred.